# Is there a way to prioritze existing requests in android's DownloadManager?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using android's DownloadManager to `enqueue` a list of files to be downloaded.
I want to respond to user event (clicking on a certain file from the list...) by pushing this download up the queue - prioritize the request using it's download id.

I've not seen any reference to this in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why do you enqueue a list of files by once? you can enqueue one by one and while the file is being downloaded you can show a list of file to the user so he can change the position of the files and upon completion of downloaded file you can take another file from beginning.

Comment: I hoped that a download manager will assist me in managing the queue but it doesn't cover that. @mmlooloo Thank you for your comment - managing it on my own seems the only way to go.